# How to remove an empty lines while exporting the text files?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cExportData AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT 'X(250)'.
DEFINE VARIABLE cPath AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cExt  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cSFTL AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT 'X(150)'.
DEFINE VARIABLE cMessageDateTime AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
      cPath  = "R:\Downloads\progress\".
      cExt   = ".Txt".
      cMessageDateTime = "123456789".



OUTPUT TO VALUE (cPath + cMessageDateTime + STRING(MTIME) + cExt ).   


     cExportData = "Data1" + CHR(10) + "Data2" + CHR(10) + "Data3" + CHR(10) + "END.".
     MESSAGE  cExportData.

OUTPUT TO CLOSE.
```

So when I see exported text file using notepad++ i could see first 3 for Data1,Data2,Data3 but 4th line is created with empty.How do I stop creating empty line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MESSAGE is not usually what you want to use for output to a file, it has many extra behaviors specific to interacting with users in the context of providing error messages etc.  PUT is generally more appropriate for writing files.  Embedding CHR(10) is also not a good idea -- that is a very OS specific line terminator.  CHR(10) is a Unix style newline but you are clearly running on Windows (which uses CHR(10) + CHR(13).

I might re-write your code as follows:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cExportData AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT 'X(250)'.
DEFINE VARIABLE cPath AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cExt  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cSFTL AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO FORMAT 'X(150)'.
DEFINE VARIABLE cMessageDateTime AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

/* the "." that you had at the ends of the ASSIGN sub statements
 * is turning it into 3 distinct statements, not one as your 
 * indentation shows
 */

ASSIGN
  cPath  = "R:\Downloads\progress\" 
  cExt   = ".Txt"
  cMessageDateTime = "123456789"
. /* end the ASSIGN statement */

/* if you are using MTIME because you imagine it will make your
 * filename unique then you are mistaken, on a multi-user or 
 * networked system it is trivial for 2 processes to create files
 * at the very same MTIME
 */

OUTPUT TO VALUE (cPath + cMessageDateTime + STRING(MTIME) + cExt ).   

/* usually some kind of looping structure would output each line
 * building the whole output by concatenating into a string will
 * eventually exhaust memory.
 */ 

put unformatted "Data1" skip "Data2" skip "Data3" skip "End." skip.

/* the final SKIP might not be needed - it is unclear to me
 * if that is a problem for your client
 */

/* as originally written this creates
 * an empty file called "CLOSE"
 */

OUTPUT /*** TO ***/ CLOSE.
```

Comment: So if we want to get unique file name then what will be the best way to do?

Comment: So if i build whole output by concatenating into string will eventually exhaust memory . If so what is the best way to do this? could you please tell sir?

Comment: If your data really is just a few fields with simple names then what you show is fine but, more usually, your data is going to be coming from some code that loops rather than from a small number of discretely named variables.  So the OUTPUT TO is usually outside the loop, the PUT statement would be inside the loop and use fields relevant to the query and, finally, the OUTPUT CLOSE is typically after the loop ends.

Comment: You might want to ask a new question about unique file names.